# jwebsocket standalone server

Tags: java

Is it possible for some one to provide an example of using jwebsocket in a standalone example?

I've been trying to follow the example at http://jwebsocket.org/howto/ht_1st_listener.htm but failing miserably.

Thanks.

ps When I mean standalone I mean "without the use of an application server such as tomcat or glassfish"

Answer (score 0):

The last release, jWebSocketServer-1.0-nb20507, and some older version already include a .bat or .sh for stand alone uses.

But in the latest version (nb20205), We can pass as parameter a websocket.xml with custom params.

Check the official site www.jwebsocket.org.

I'm still looking for a step by step stand alone implementation, by my own :( ...